# Hibernate bad configurated: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured

Tags: hibernate, localhost, hibernate.cfg.xml

This is my "hibernate.cfg.xml", i'm trying to connec to my localhost(postgres) and i'm not sure if i'm typing well the values for the parameters (for example the connection url or the others):

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
  <session-factory>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password">quesooloroso</property>
    <property name="connection.autocommit">false</property>
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>
    <mapping resource="model/Comprobante.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Parametro.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Usuario.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Detalleitinerario.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Configusuario.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Notaalmacen.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Perfilxventana.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Ruta.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Pedido.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Itinerario.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Privilegio.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Modulo.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Ventana.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Perfilxprivilegio.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Persona.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Almacen.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Cargo.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Continente.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Logusuario.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Reservaalmacen.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Tipousuario.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Pais.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Perfil.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Vuelo.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Vueloxruta.hbm.xml"/>
    <mapping resource="model/Logpedido.hbm.xml"/>
  </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is my the part of my code where my program fails I guess:

```
public Frm_SimularAlmacen() {
        //1. Consultar todos los almacenes
        almacenes_consultaBD = consultarAlmacenes();
        //2. Armar el String[]
        initComponents();
    }

private List<Almacen> consultarAlmacenes(){
    Session session = Utils.openConnection();
    Query queryResult = session.createQuery("from Almacen");
    return queryResult.list();

}
```

This is my output:

```
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.Version <clinit>
Información: Hibernate Annotations 3.3.1.GA
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
Información: Hibernate 3.2.5
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
Información: hibernate.properties not found
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment buildBytecodeProvider
Información: Bytecode provider name : cglib
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Environment <clinit>
Información: using JDK 1.4 java.sql.Timestamp handling
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration configure
Información: configuring from resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration getConfigurationInputStream
Información: Configuration resource: /hibernate.cfg.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Comprobante.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Parametro.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Usuario.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Detalleitinerario.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Configusuario.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Notaalmacen.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:20 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Perfilxventana.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Ruta.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Pedido.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Itinerario.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Privilegio.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Modulo.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Ventana.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Perfilxprivilegio.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Persona.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Almacen.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Cargo.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Continente.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Logusuario.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Reservaalmacen.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Tipousuario.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Pais.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Perfil.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Vuelo.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Vueloxruta.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration addResource
Información: Reading mappings from resource : model/Logpedido.hbm.xml
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration doConfigure
Información: Configured SessionFactory: null
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Comprobante -> comprobante
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Parametro -> parametro
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Usuario -> usuario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Detalleitinerario -> detalleitinerario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Configusuario -> configusuario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Notaalmacen -> notaalmacen
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Perfilxventana -> perfilxventana
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Ruta -> ruta
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Pedido -> pedido
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Itinerario -> itinerario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Privilegio -> privilegio
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Modulo -> modulo
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Ventana -> ventana
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Perfilxprivilegio -> perfilxprivilegio
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Persona -> persona
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Almacen -> almacen
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Cargo -> cargo
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Continente -> continente
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Logusuario -> logusuario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Reservaalmacen -> reservaalmacen
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Tipousuario -> tipousuario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Pais -> pais
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Perfil -> perfil
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Vuelo -> vuelo
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Vueloxruta -> vueloxruta
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindRootPersistentClassCommonValues
Información: Mapping class: model.Logpedido -> logpedido
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Parametro.pedidos -> pedido
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Parametro.comprobantes -> comprobante
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Parametro.vuelos -> vuelo
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Parametro.personasForIdtipodocumento -> persona
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Parametro.personasForIdtipopersona -> persona
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Usuario.logpedidos -> logpedido
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Usuario.logusuarios -> logusuario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Usuario.personas -> persona
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Usuario.notaalmacens -> notaalmacen
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Usuario.comprobantes -> comprobante
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Configusuario.tipousuarios -> tipousuario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Ruta.pedidos -> pedido
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Ruta.vueloxrutas -> vueloxruta
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Ruta.itinerarios -> itinerario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Pedido.reservaalmacens -> reservaalmacen
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Pedido.comprobantes -> comprobante
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Pedido.logpedidos -> logpedido
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Pedido.detalleitinerarios -> detalleitinerario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Itinerario.detalleitinerarios -> detalleitinerario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Privilegio.perfilxprivilegios -> perfilxprivilegio
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Modulo.ventanas -> ventana
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Ventana.logusuarios -> logusuario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Ventana.perfilxventanas -> perfilxventana
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Persona.pedidos -> pedido
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Almacen.reservaalmacens -> reservaalmacen
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Almacen.vuelosForOrigen -> vuelo
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Almacen.vuelosForDestino -> vuelo
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Cargo.usuarios -> usuario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Continente.paises -> pais
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Reservaalmacen.notaalmacens -> notaalmacen
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Tipousuario.usuarios -> usuario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Pais.almacens -> almacen
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Pais.personas -> persona
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Perfil.perfilxventanas -> perfilxventana
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Perfil.usuarios -> usuario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Perfil.perfilxprivilegios -> perfilxprivilegio
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Vuelo.vueloxrutas -> vueloxruta
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Vuelo.detalleitinerarios -> detalleitinerario
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.HbmBinder bindCollectionSecondPass
Información: Mapping collection: model.Vuelo.logpedidos -> logpedido
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationConfiguration secondPassCompile
Información: Hibernate Validator not found: ignoring
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
Información: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
Información: Hibernate connection pool size: 20
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
Información: autocommit mode: false
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
Información: using driver: org.postgresql.Driver at URL: jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/postgres
oct 25, 2012 2:57:21 AM org.hibernate.connection.DriverManagerConnectionProvider configure
Información: connection properties: {user=postgres, password=****, autocommit=false}
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: RDBMS: PostgreSQL, version: 9.2.1
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: JDBC driver: PostgreSQL Native Driver, version: PostgreSQL 9.1 JDBC4 (build 901)
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect <init>
Información: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionFactoryFactory buildTransactionFactory
Información: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.transaction.TransactionManagerLookupFactory getTransactionManagerLookup
Información: No TransactionManagerLookup configured (in JTA environment, use of read-write or transactional second-level cache is not recommended)
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Automatic flush during beforeCompletion(): disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Automatic session close at end of transaction: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: JDBC batch size: 15
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: JDBC batch updates for versioned data: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Scrollable result sets: enabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: JDBC3 getGeneratedKeys(): enabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Connection release mode: auto
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Default batch fetch size: 1
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Generate SQL with comments: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Order SQL updates by primary key: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Order SQL inserts for batching: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createQueryTranslatorFactory
Información: Query translator: org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.hql.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory <init>
Información: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Query language substitutions: {}
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: JPA-QL strict compliance: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Second-level cache: enabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Query cache: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory createCacheProvider
Información: Cache provider: org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Optimize cache for minimal puts: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Structured second-level cache entries: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Echoing all SQL to stdout
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Statistics: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Deleted entity synthetic identifier rollback: disabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Default entity-mode: pojo
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.cfg.SettingsFactory buildSettings
Información: Named query checking : enabled
oct 25, 2012 2:57:22 AM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl <init>
Información: building session factory
oct 25, 2012 2:57:23 AM org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryObjectFactory addInstance
Información: Not binding factory to JNDI, no JNDI name configured
Hibernate: select almacen0_.idalmacen as idalmacen15_, almacen0_.idpais as idpais15_, almacen0_.latitud as latitud15_, almacen0_.longitud as longitud15_, almacen0_.nombreciudad as nombreci5_15_, almacen0_.nombreaeropuerto as nombreae6_15_, almacen0_.stock as stock15_, almacen0_.fechacreacion as fechacre8_15_, almacen0_.estado as estado15_, almacen0_.capacidad as capacidad15_, almacen0_.nombre as nombre15_, almacen0_.ultimamodificacion as ultimam12_15_ from public.almacen almacen0_
oct 25, 2012 2:57:23 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
Advertencia: SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42P01
oct 25, 2012 2:57:23 AM org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter logExceptions
Grave: ERROR: no existe la relación «public.almacen»
  Position: 451
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2223)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.hql.QueryLoader.list(QueryLoader.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.list(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:338)
    at org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.performList(HQLQueryPlan.java:172)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.list(SessionImpl.java:1121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.QueryImpl.list(QueryImpl.java:79)
    at pe.edu.pucp.dp1.TSPSolution.view.sim.almacen.Frm_SimularAlmacen.consultarAlmacenes(Frm_SimularAlmacen.java:29)
    at pe.edu.pucp.dp1.TSPSolution.view.sim.almacen.Frm_SimularAlmacen.<init>(Frm_SimularAlmacen.java:35)
    at pe.edu.pucp.dp1.TSPSolution.view.componentes.Index$8.actionPerformed(Index.java:270)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2018)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2341)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.doClick(AbstractButton.java:376)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI.doClick(BasicMenuItemUI.java:833)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuItemUI$Handler.mouseReleased(BasicMenuItemUI.java:877)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6505)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6270)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2229)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4861)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2287)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4832)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4492)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4422)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2273)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2719)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4687)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:703)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(EventQueue.java:102)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:662)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:660)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:87)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:676)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:674)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:673)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:244)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:163)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:151)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:147)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:139)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:97)
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: no existe la relación «public.almacen»
  Position: 451
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2103)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1836)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:257)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:512)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:388)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:273)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2220)
    ... 48 more
```

It's my first time with hibernate, so i apologies if i'm not giving enough information or if it's too confusing.

Comment: How did this go? It looks like the table `public.almacen` does not exist in the database.

Answer (score -1):

In your DAO class, try this lines.

```
SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure(
                    "hibernate.cfg.xml")
                    .buildSessionFactory();
```

Comment: I don't think it is a good idea to put the session factory creation code in DAO.